# Cannot get scala file to run

Tags: scala

I have 2 questions:

1) I'm trying to get the List *menu* in this program to appear either by calling scalac then scala or print it using the REPL but I'm a little confused because this uses packages. I tried to run this using

```
scalac Fruits.scala
scala bobsdelight\Fruits
```

but I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bobsdelights\Fruits wrong name: bobsdelights/Fruits)`

If someone can please show me how to execute this script that would be great

2)I'm also trying to create a new Apple object by calling `new Fruits.Apple` in the REPL by loading the file first but I get:

```
error: type Apple is not a member of object Fruits
 new Fruits.Apple``
```

This example is in the Programming In Scala book.

```
package bobsdelights

abstract class Fruit(
  val name: String,
  val color: String
)

object Fruits {
  object Apple extends Fruit("apple", "red")
  object Orange extends Fruit("orange", "orange")
  object Pear extends Fruit("pear", "yellowish")
  val menu = List(Apple, Orange, Pear)
}
```

Comment: Could you drop full content of Fruits.scala ?

Comment: that is all of it.

Comment: Create actual class definition Fruits. Singelton has different class like Fruits$ etc.

Comment: @Pavel you get static forwarders from the "ordinary" class to the object class, so Fruits class has a main if Fruits has one.

Comment: If you are just learning or mocking some logic general advise will be to use scala workscheets.

Comment: I'd recommend using `sbt`, directly using `scalac` is the path to madness.

Answer (score 1):

REPL example:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :pa bobsdelight.scala
Pasting file bobsdelight.scala...

scala> Fruits.menu
<console>:12: error: not found: value Fruits
       Fruits.menu
       ^

scala> import bobsdelight._
<console>:11: error: not found: value bobsdelight
       import bobsdelight._
              ^

scala> import bobsdelights._
import bobsdelights._

scala> Fruits.menu
res1: List[bobsdelights.Fruit] = List(bobsdelights.Fruits$Apple$@6c17c0f8, bobsdelights.Fruits$Orange$@260e3837, bobsdelights.Fruits$Pear$@88b76f2)
```

If you try to "run" a class with no main method:

```
$ scala bobsdelights.Fruits
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bobsdelights.Fruits.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Idiom for runnable app:

```
object Fruits extends App {
  object Apple extends Fruit("apple", "red")
  object Orange extends Fruit("orange", "orange")
  object Pear extends Fruit("pear", "yellowish")
  val menu = List(Apple, Orange, Pear)

  println(menu)
}
```

and

```
$ scalac bobsdelight.scala && scala bobsdelights.Fruits
List(bobsdelights.Fruits$Apple$@4f8e5cde, bobsdelights.Fruits$Orange$@504bae78, bobsdelights.Fruits$Pear$@3b764bce)
```